# vanillaXarm error on Jetson TK1, XiApi Installation

Tags: linux, arm, embedded-linux, ximea

When I try to install XiAPi to Jetson TK1 (Jetson Dev Pack L4T r21.4 installed, USB3.0 enabled), I get the error:

```
root@tegra-ubuntu:/home/ubuntu/Downloads/package# ./install 
Installing XIMEA Linux Software Package
Instaling ARM32 version
This is installation of package for platform -arm32
Checking if user is super user
OK
Installing and reloading udev rules
OK
OK
OK
Installing libusb
cp: cannot stat ‘libs/libusb/vanillaXarm/lib*’: No such file or directory
Error on previous command
```

I also got the same error on the Grinch Kernel installed Jetson too.

How can this error be fixed? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copied the folder package/libs/libusb/vanillaXarm32, and renamed the copy as vanillaXarm

Tried to install again, then it updated me with similar errors. Fixed the remaining problems with the similar approach above.

Now XiApi is installed on my Jetson, and everything works fine